# Convert the filename into project requirement pattern

Tags: batch-file

I want to convert this GIF file in same folder

muz-171669-JA_fig_10.gif

muz-171669-JA_fig_11a.gif

In this pattern:

1. **muz**  is convert to **muz12345**

Here in numeric value **"171669"** only last 4 digit must be taken means:

2. **"171669"** is convert to **1669**
3. **fig_10** is convert to this value **f010**.

Sometime name is like this **fig_11a**  so in that case it should be convert into this way:
**f11a**

There are hundreds of gif files with such filename

with suffix **fig_01  till fig_999**.

And it should be convert like this:

suffix **f001 till f999**

Sometimes **fig_11a** suffix occur in that case it should be convert like this **f011a.**

The output of the following :

muz-17**1669**-JA_fig_10.gif

muz-17**1669**-JA_fig_11a.gif

must be like this:

muz12345**1669**f010.gif

muz12345**1669**f11a.gif

I am doing this manually and it takes lots of my time.My friend told me that this is possible using batch extension. but i dont have must knowledge in batch command.

Can anyone help me out? its project requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "tokens=1-7delims=-_." %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\muz-*-*_*_*.gif" '
  ) DO (
  IF "%%g"=="" (
   SET "num2=%%b"
   SET "fig=%%d"
   SET "num3=00%%e"
   ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%%a-%%b-%%c_%%d_%%e.%%f" "muz12345!num2:~-4!!fig:~0,1!!num3:~-3!.%%f"
  )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should process the files appropriately. You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.